# LiveCode - in-app purchasing testing issue

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, livecode

I'm trying to test in-App purchasing of a non-consumable product (a subscription to content which is stored on our own server).

I have Sandbox testers set up in iTunes Connect.

The purchase routine is as follows:

```
on purchaseMonthlySub
   mobileStoreEnablePurchaseUpdates
   mobileStoreSetProductType "com.softcast.flschoollaw.SCHOOLAWMONTHLY", "inapp"
   mobileStoreMakePurchase "com.softcast.flschoollaw.SCHOOLAWMONTHLY", "1", "This is a monthly subscription to FLSLG"
end purchaseMonthlySub
```

...and I have the standard handler for purchaseStateUpdate.

I have side-loaded the built app onto my iPhone via xCode for testing, since In-App Purchasing doesn't work in simulation. The product **is** listed as "Ready To Submit" in iTunes Connect.

When the routine executes, I get prompted **twice** for the Apple ID and password, and then I get the dreaded "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" message. This happens with a brand-new, never-before-used Sandbox test account.

I've checked the Apple FAQ tech note regarding in-app purchases, but to no avail. Would appreciate any and all help with whatever I might be missing here... this is for a client, and I'm already late delivering them something that works -- much thanks.

Comment: Do you have a paid Apple dev account or do you use a free provisioning profile?

Comment: Which versions of LiveCode and XCode do you use? Does your app have access to internet?

Comment: Yes, I have a paid Apple developer account. I'm using a distribution profile I created via developer.apple.com.  LiveCode version is 7.0.5 (commercial) and the XCode version is 6.3.2. -- thx

Comment: Yes to your second question also Mark (sorry, missed that earlier)

Comment: could it possibly be related to the fact that we have a Tax Agreement pending (i.e. not yet completed) in iTunes Connect?

Comment: It always was very easy to accept the tax agreement. You could just accept it and test again. However, pending agreements never affected my test set-up.

Comment: Well, the people I'm working for will do that (they have their own iTunes Connect login). Otherwise it's my name on the W-9 form. Maybe that's not it... I'm out of answers. There's gotta be some LiveCode user out there who has run up against this problem.